# Javascript link making target blank?

Tags: javascript

I have made a Javascript link maker...

```
document.write('http://imgur.com'.link('http://www.imgur.com'));
```

How I can make this open the link target in a new window, like `target="blank"`?

Comment: You will have to rewrite the code inside this "link maker". Without seeing this code we really can't help you.

Comment: And if you want help with that, you should post the code for link(), which I assume was added to String.prototype

Comment: That is all the code...I am not sure what more you are asking please?  Why is this -2 when nobody knows the answer?

Comment: I made it!  it is just a simple link maker...it makes a link...that is all...but I want to open in new window...

Comment: He used the function [link()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp)

Comment: @David19801 Why don't you create your own link function? Womething saimple that will append your code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize such a function existed... in that case you'll probably want to write a custom 'link' function and add it to String.prototype to override the normal one.

Comment: @JeanValijean - That is just a part of javascript I did not make link()...I don't know why this has -2...

Comment: @David19801 Eh Eh! I got a -1 too. However, maybe you got a -2 because the question is not clear

Comment: Sorry had a blonde moment and thought you made your own link maker - next time please use `@` to notify, could save some time. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a new "link builder" to override the built in link function, and its usage:

```
function mylink(url) {
  return "<a href=\"" + url + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + this + "</a>"
}

String.prototype.link = mylink
document.write('http://imgur.com'.link('http://www.imgur.com'));
```

Comment: I don't know! However, I can say that your answer is very elegant. Congrats

Comment: The truth can't be hidden! Even with display:none!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to add a link to a container. E.g.:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

And the Javascript is:

```
addLink('value', 'http://jsfiddle.net');

function addLink(text, url){
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("container");
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href',url);
    a.setAttribute('target','_blank');
    a.innerHTML = text;
    mydiv.appendChild(a);
}
```

This is a working JSFiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tN7Kq/)

Comment: Jquery not allowed because it is on Wordpress...sorry

Comment: Ok, I will prepare a Javascript function instead with a JSFiddle